# admob banner and Interstitial dont apper when I put my UnitId

Tags: android, admob

I follow these tutorial to implement admob banner and Interstitial in my app:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial

and they work normally with test unitIds that admob provide.

But when I change these test unitIds and put my own those I get from my admob account, and run the app on my mobile device, they no longer appear.
what's the problem? do I have to wait to generate signed apk?

Comment: Are you using the debug mode?

Comment: I just press (shift+f10), is that mean I'm running it in debugging mode? @MatPag

Comment: To test your ads in your device with an unpublished app, you need to follow some instructions specified in the admob guide [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#enable_test_devices)

Comment: @MatPag it works with test mode, but when I change the UnitId with my own it don't work

Comment: Are you sure the app package-name is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Once you check debug apk on the your mobile device it will works fine.